# Mockito vs Mocktail in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have started to write tests. I saw `mockito` and `mocktail` as the most used testing libraries. I couldn't find any question/articles that explains differences between them. If there is a experienced developers -who used both of them- can you explain differences/advantages/disadvantages of them? Which one should I prefer?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**1.** Assuming that you are new with Flutter, it would be probably easier for you to utilize the [mocktail](https://pub.dev/packages/mocktail) package.

The main "inconvenience" with the [mockito](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito) package is that you     need to generate the mocks running **flutter pub run build_runner     build**, define meta-annotations like **@GenerateMocks**, and imports like **xxx.mocks.dart**, and an extra **build_runner** dev dependency at your **pubspec.yaml**.

The [mocktail](https://pub.dev/packages/mocktail) package simplifies mocking: you just need to extend the Mock class. That's it. Without code-generating, annotations, "magic" **xxx.mocks.dart** imports.

**2.** Also, you have to keep in mind that the **mocktail** package is very new and has a stable history of just 10 months. The **mockito** package is a proven by time and developers library that has almost 8 years of history of stable releases: the library is well-known and is widespread among the Flutter and Dart community.

With the experience, you will better understand which library better fits your projects' needs.

**PS:** you can take a look at the code snippets of both packages.

**The mocktail snippet:**

```dart
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';

// Real Cat class
class Cat {
  // ...
}

// Mock Cat Class
class MockCat extends Mock implements Cat{}

void main() {
  // Create a Mock Cat instance
  final cat = MockCat();
}
```

**The mockito snippet screenshot**

```dart
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart'
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart'

import 'cat.mocks.dart';

// REAL class
class Cat {
 // ...
}

// Annotation which generates the cat.mocks.dart library
@GenerateMocks([Cat])
void main() {
  // Create a mock object
  final cat = MockCat();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this good answer man! I have one more question though. Am I able to "spy" instead of "mock" in one of them? I learned that spy keyword is deprecated from mockito. Still enable us to spy but a little bit tedious. What about mocktail?

Comment: I'm going to give the classic SO answer to that: Although you want to use spy you should not. If you have to use spy it means your code is not structured very well (that's why it is deprecated).

Answer (score 14):

Answering my own question after experiencing both of them:

At first I decided to use mockito since it has more reputation. But, it was difficult to regenerate mock classes again and again. But then, I wanted to give a chance to mocktail and definitely saw that it is better! I would recommend using that instead of mockito for a few advantages. Being not have to generate mock classes is NOT the only advantage!